# Multiple Select box in Codeigniter returning string instead of array of values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting a strange behaviour.

In a view in Codeigniter I have this code:

```
<?php echo form_multiselect('post-categories', $active_categories, (!empty($selected_categories))?$selected_categories:null,array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
```

Which generates the following HTML

```
<select name="post-categories" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Beauty</option>
<option value="4">More</option>
<option value="3">New</option>
</select>
```

However when I submit the form with multiple categories selected I receive only strings.

In the controller

```
var_dump($this->input->post('post-categories'));
```

will output

```
string(1) "3"
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` should be `post-categories[]` (array syntax). Try -

```
form_multiselect('post-categories[]', $active_categories, (!empty($selected_categories))?$selected_categories:null,array('class'=>'form-control'));
```